# Eclipse wants class in constructor?

Tags: java, eclipse

Ok, forget it.  Just realized I forgot the brackets.

Good lord.  I need a rest.

I'm designing my own double linked list.

```
public class DoubleLinkedList {

    public DoubleLinkedList {

    }

}
```

That's the extent of my code so far.  Eclipse is underlining the `public` in the constructor and telling me:

"Syntax error on token `"public"`, class expected after this token"

It's a constructor, why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `()` on your constructor.  Try

```
public DoubleLinkedList() {
}
```

Otherwise it's either a bad class definition or a bad variable definition, and Eclipse must have assumed the former.

Answer (score 2):

Constructor must have the parenthesis `()`.

Do like this:

```
public class DoubleLinkedList {
    public DoubleLinkedList() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this

```
public DoubleLinkedList() {


}
```